# How do i set a height on a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div

```
div id='srch'
```

that has a computed height of 7000px how do i set the height of the another div to the same on window.load

```
div id='set_me'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('set_me').style.height = 
    document.getElementById('srch').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: +1 Same answer as Spooks, but you took the time to add 4 spacebars

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('set_me').style.height = document.getElementById('srch').offsetHeight +'px';
```

if the possibility of the srch height will ever change, it will always match